# ArcMap editor panel window not opening

Tags: gis, arcgis

I have installed `ArcMap Desktop 10.5.1` on a new computer and have a problem. I have never experienced with any previous versions of ArcMap.

1. Pressing the button of the toolbar for the Editor
2. I can’t access the toolbar.
3. I also can see that the program notices that I have pressed the button by the ArcMap-window ‘flickering’ and I see the Editor-window that should open for less than a second at some occasions.
4. I have tried to see if it ends up hidden somewhere, but it does not seems like it.
5. Printscreen of the ArcMap window with the editor button  [image: Printscreen of the ArcMap window with the editor button]

**Does anyone know what can be the problem and how to handle it?**

I have tried to search for answers both at the ESRI help-page, here in stackoverflow and in other broad search engines, but this doesn’t seem to be a common problem.

Comment: I think this would be better asked at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find that forum previously. Have posted the q there now.

Comment: It's a site for focused Q&A so be sure to take its Tour.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/251245/115

Answer (score 0):

This problem can have many causes and there are 2 different ways to open the editor toolbar.

1. Try click `Customize > Toolbars > Editor` (I will add a pic for it)
2. Right-click while your mouse on the main menu. The toolbar will be open directly and check the editor. Same solution.

If you have still this problem you must see another reason for the problem.
For example, do you using a second monitor? If you using it maybe the editor toolbar coming from another monitor. Check your monitor/monitors also.

If you still have problems, please write. There is another solution.
However, I am not writing now because it will reset usage of interface.

[image]